# Dynamically adding classes in Vue based on value

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm facing an issue with adding dynamic styling to an element based on it's contents.

```
<td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.limitCardStatus }}</td>
```

The values of the `limitCardStatus` key are stored in several objects, and are as follows: "Active, Inactive, Sample".

What i want to achieve is to color "Active" green, "Inactive" red, and "Sample" yellow.

What i've have so far is: I generated the coresponding CSS classes & styles,
and i tried using `v-for` with `:class`, but i can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the full table:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="limitCards" hide-actions>
 <template v-slot:items="props">
  <td class="tableNumber text-xs-left">{{ props.item.number }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.limitCardNumber }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.productCode }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.plannedAmount }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.productName }}</td>
  <td
     class="text-xs-left"
     :class="{
     'green--text': limitCardStatus === 'Active',
     'yellow--text': limitCardStatus === 'Inactive',
     'yellow--text': limitCardStatus === 'Sample',
     }"
     >{{ props.item.limitCardStatus }}</td>
  </template>
 </v-data-table>

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with the dynamic classes like so

```
<div
  class="text-xs-left"
  :class="{
    'green-color--text': limitCardStatus === 'Active',
    'yellow-color--text': limitCardStatus === 'Inactive',
    'yellow-color--text': limitCardStatus === 'Sample',
  }"
>{{ props.item.limitCardStatus }}</div>
```

More information is [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Thank you sir, that's wonderful! I will accept your answer in 5 minutes, because it wont let me at the moment.

Comment: Hmm, i've tried your apporach, but i'm getting this error:
```Property or method "limitCardStatus" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.```
At the moment, the limitCardStatus data is stored in hardcoded array of objects, and i've tried reffering it by the array itself, and with ```this.```, but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pok3rPrinc3 all you need is to replace my/your variable `limitCardStatus ` to the one where your status is. Mb it has to by something like `props.item.limitCardStatus`

Comment: Yeah, i've tried that at some point aswell :) The problem was: ```'yellow-color--text'``` is actually ```yellow--text```. Still your answer was the right one!

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner approach is to use [ES6 computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript)

Assuming you're passing in prop named `limitCardStatus` to the component,

```
  <td
     class="text-xs-left"
     :class="{ [limitCardStatus]: 1 }"
     >{{ props.item.limitCardStatus }}</td>
```

`1` is just there because there must be a truthy value on the right side for vue to apply the class name, you could do `{{ [limitCardStatus]: limitCardStatus }}` if you're not always passing in `limitCardStatus` prop to the component.

After, you can just replace CSS selectors for `.green-text` etc... with `.Active` `.Inactive` and `.Sample`